# symfony security Login(Invalid credentials.)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm using Symfony3.4 and php7.1

My app has a form login. Everything looks right
even on local I can login without any problem.
But **on the Server** host my app shows an **Invalid credentials** error.

```
# security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        AdminBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AdminBundle:User
                property: username


    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_security_token
                csrf_token_id: a_private_string
                require_previous_session: true
                post_only:      true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
                invalidate_session: false
                delete_cookies:
                    a: { path: null, domain: null }
                    b: { path: null, domain: null }

            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
                        # activate different ways to authenticate

           # http_basic: ~
                        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

                        # form_login: ~
                        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
    access_control:

        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin_Cp, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }


    role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

this is my loginAction

```
   public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('AdminBundle:User:login_user.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
```

If you want more information about this question.I can immediately update the question

Comment: did you create new user on the server or import them from local?

Comment: Yes, I did it.i create new user on the server..

Comment: please add the User entity

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: fucethebads ::Your solution was correct..After clearing the cache it worked correctly.Thankful